# Preview button which when clicked changes the page's background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I run a free resource site providing tileable/seamless patterns and I'm trying to add a button (with a script) in my posts which visitors can click to change the background image of the page so that they can preview the pattern in action. So for instance on this post (http://tileablepatterns.com/denim-pattern/) I'd want the user to be able to click on a button/link which would change the background image from the grey background to the denim pattern.

How do I go about doing this? Also, preferably I'd want it to be a simple script that I can just insert into the post instead of having to edit theme files.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Give your button an ID, for example: id="button" and then the following should work:

```
$('#button').click(function(){ $('body').css('background', 'url(http://tileablepatterns.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Denim.jpg) repeat 0 0'); });
```

Comment: Thanks, so something like this? <button type="button">Preview</button> and <script type="text/javascript">
$('#button').click(function(){ $('body').css('background', 'url(http://tileablepatterns.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Denim.jpg) repeat 0 0'); });
</script>

Comment: A few changes: add an id="button" attribute in the button element. And before your jQuery code in the script tag do $(document).ready(function(){ and then close it with });

Comment: Made the corrections but doesn't work unfortunately:
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){$('#button').click(function(){ $('body').css('background', 'url(http://tileablepatterns.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Denim.jpg) repeat 0 0'); });
});
</script> 

<button type="button" id="button">Preview</button>

Comment: 1.) is jquery included? 2.) do you have errors in the console? 3.) js should be at the end of the body after the html

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by 1 and 2?

Comment: Can I see your source? According to other comments, you might be including jquery twice, which may cause this not to work.

Answer (score 1):

So basically I tried this `<button onclick="document.body.style.background = 'url(http://tileablepatterns.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Denim.jpg) no-repeat center center'">change bg</button>`

And it adds two white lines to the existing background, one close to the top and one close to the bottom but it's not changing the entire background. I think there's a wrapper over the background or something but I don't know how to change the code so that it changes the entire page's background including the wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

If I were to do this using jQuery, I'd take a modular approach and one that's easy to template in HTML and still works when Javascript fails.

Start with some basic markup (I'm using Baconmockup as a sample image):

```
<div id="page" class="container">
    <!-- Note that we're defining both href as well as two html5 attributes called data-src and data-background-change (data-background-change is what indicates that this particular link has some special functionality and data-src is the the source for the script below) -->
    <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/baconmockup/img/baconmockup-470-300.jpg" data-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/baconmockup/img/baconmockup-470-300.jpg" data-background-change>Click me</a>
</div>
```

And a bit of CSS:

```
// The container is your page, and the background we'll change in this example.
div.container {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

And finally in main.js:

```
$(function () {

    $.fn.changeBackgroundOnClick = function () {

        var target = this[0];
        var image = target.getAttribute('data-src');

        $(target).on('click', function(e) {

            // If JS is enabled, the click will prevent the browser from navigating to the image.
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#page').css({
                'background-image' : 'url(' + image + ')',
                'background-size' : 'cover',
                'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat'
            });
        });

        return this;
    }

    // We can now iterate over every element with data-background-change to give it the functionality you need. No code needs to be repeated. :)
    $('a[data-background-change]').each(function () {
        $(this).changeBackgroundOnClick(); 
    });

});
```

Good luck.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nyyby/31/

Comment: Tried what was in the fiddle inline and it doesn't work (I did everything inline by the way).

Comment: Make sure it is in script tags after jQuery is linked in your <head></head>. JSfiddle is the equivalent of writing JS inline.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure how to do this? I mean how do I link jQuery?

Comment: Okay well. Looking at your source code I can see that you've linked jQuery twice already. You've included jquery 1.7 as well as jquery 1.11. 

That is likely causing conflict issues, and could very well be the source of your problems here.

My suggestion is to remove the jquery at the end of your document and try again:

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Sorry I don't understand (forgive me, I'm new to this stuff), I just pasted what you suggested?

Comment: Do you know how to access your wordpress site with FTP (like Filezilla or maybe Coda)?

Comment: Not sure but I'm in my cPanel, is that it?

Comment: Also, I removed the other script and it worked. But can you give me an example that changes the entire background of the page (instead of just the div)?

Comment: In the javascript part of the code above, change #page to .bg-image.master and you should see the entire grey part of the background change.

Comment: That didn't work, the page just refreshes but nothing changes.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm calling it a day. I'll try a few more things and if they don't work I'll email you for sure! :)